# Disabling Preview's "sliding" animation

Tags: preview

The pages of my pdf presentation add incremental changes to the first page. The second page, for instance, consists of the diagram on the first page in addition to a few more lines. This way a complex figure can be introduced gradually.

But Preview now "slides" each page, which defeats the effect I am after (a few changes just appear). Instead the audience is treated to a distracting effect.

Is there a way to disable the fancy sliding and go back to replacing pages?

Comment: The animations have been removed on 10.8. But there's some serious visual bugs when changing pages on my installation. [Can anyone reproduce them?](http://superuser.com/a/357882/69039)

Comment: Another reason why Lion is a skipper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> to navigate pages without the sliding effect.

Comment: Perfect (almost). Option does it. I wish it would be caps-lock or something like it such that I don't have to always keep in mind pressing a modifier key, but it will do just fine.

Comment: works great and is not a bother - just as long as I can _remember_ to use the _Option_  key ;)    I wonder who would actually _prefer_ that annoying animation) - and by extension why it is the _default_ behavior ..

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround - use Skim. It has better tools for full-screen presentations anyway.

http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/

Note - native Lion full-screen doesn't work yet, but the non-native fullscreen works fine.

Comment: I'd really like to avoid installing something else. Preview is already decent. It's light-weight and launches super fast, and yet has just the right features compared to that other behemoth's product. Unfortunately Apple has been trying to move Preview in the direction of super-power without giving it the (astonishing, in a bad way) list of customizations. But not having a customization at all is worse than having hundreds.

Comment: Seriously - try Skim. It is not a behemoth! It is a lightweight fast, free PDKkit based viewer designed for academics - i.e. for annotation and giving presentations - Preview was not designed with presenting in mind and its presentation output has always been somewhat second rate. Seriously, give Skim a try. I consider it a must-have app.

Comment: @dan8394 is right!  Skim is pretty nice.  It is frustrating that Lion seems to have a lot of little things like this that are 1) not useful, 2) get in the way, 3) cannot be disabled easily, if at all.

Comment: A year later, I agree. Skim is as nimble as Preview and has a few features (split panes, notes pane) that will be essential to some users. Note that in the meantime my question has become irrelevant if you switch to Mountain Lion. Preview on ML is reported not to animate page transitions (or perhaps it no longer animates at all).

Answer (score -1):

Um...If you go to "View" then click "Continuous Scroll", everything should go back to normal.

Comment: The scrolling is no longer per page with this option selected, and even if you line up the page down action, it has the animation that this question is trying to remove.